# Link each specific image with position in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, carousel

As I said... I want to **link each specific image to the position in modal carousel.** 
Now I have only that first is active image and it opens everytime when any image is clicked.

Sorry but I'm not very good at JavaScript at all. 
I'll be really glad if you help me with this.

### Thanks.

---

**Script:**

```
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
                    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].onclick = function () {
          modal.style.display = "block";
          modalImg.src = this.src;
          modalImg.alt = this.alt;
          captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
      };
  }
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  span.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  };
  function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";};
        $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', centerModal);$(window).on("resize", function () {$('.modal:visible').each(centerModal);});
```

---

**Modal Carousel Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="gallery text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div id="carousel-modal-demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9999999999999">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="7"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="8"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="9"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="10"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="11"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="12"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="13"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="14"></li>
                    </ol>



                    <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                        <div class="item active"> 
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <main class="item">
                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>

                        </main>
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div> 
                        <main class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </main>
                        <main class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </main> 
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <p class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </p> 
                        <p class="item"> 
                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </p>



                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-modal-demo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-modal-demo" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a> 

                    </div> 
                </div>  
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get index of the clicked image and pass this to carousel().

Change your for loop with this

```
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
images[i].onclick = function () {
   modal.style.display = "block";
   var index= $(this).closest("div").index();
    $('#carousel-modal-demo').carousel(index);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm :)